# Run an exe file with dependencies VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, exe

I know there are plenty of questions about this topic but I reviewed them and I couldn't find what I need.

I need to run an exe in VB.Net but that exe needs some files that are in the exe's folder. When I try to run the exe using `Shell` or `Process.Start()` the exe looks for those files in my app folder (and throws an error) instead of the exe original folder. I can't move my app exe nor the external exe.

Comment: Are you refering to running a program from Visual Studio for debugging or running the final compiled exe in a real deployement? What files are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [**Directory.SetCurrentDirectory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) Method ? It sets the application's current working directory to the specified directory. change the example below with the path of the application you want to execute prior calling it.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\test")
Console.WriteLine("Current directory: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
'Execute an application from C:\test
```

Output :

```
Current directory: C:\test
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the Windows startup path:

```
exePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
```